# How to make my website SEO friendly while using Restful API?

Tags: seo, api, restful

I'm using lumen on the backend and simple JQuery on the front end. Soon I'll be shifting towards the angular front end.

But one thing that has been the cause of my tension is how should I make my website SEO friendly.

All I know about SEO till now is that each page should have unique meta tags and keywords and other stuff that lies in the head of a page.

But using Restful API I don't know if I can change meta tags as javascript acts only after the page has been loaded.So my question is how to make my website SEO friendly while using RESTful API.

**Edit:**
Considering comments I think I need a little more explanation in my question.The markup is rendered before the content of the page as I'm using RESTful API so I can't have a dynamic name according to the topic the page is about.
Consider an example I'm having blogs since the blogs will be fetched after the DOM is loaded.So it will be bad as I'll need to change my meta tags after the page is rendered so it'll badly affect the crawler.

Comment: Angular delivers your markup. Markup = SEO. You'll control what markup Angular will deliver and by that make your website SEO friendly.

Comment: And what about the ones without  angular and using simple Jquery

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to do. You'll build a page from maybe JSON output and then have jQuery build the markup??? Please don't. Will you have markup? Fine! Then you can do SEO as well.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! You are presuming that the page will get indexed before it's done loading. I think that's a misconception. Robots will wait until page is completely loaded and than index what they get and crawl on.

Comment: Can you please make an answer of what you are saying and giving source for reference @leymannx

Comment: Please read the following article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/seo-vs-react-is-it-neccessary-to-render-react-pages-in-the-backend-74ce5015c0c9

**Many people still worry that if you build a websites using tools like React, Angular, or Ember, it will hurt your search engine ranking.**

Comment: Can't answer anymore as the question was put on hold now.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother I'll consider your suggestion @leymannx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67401/discussion-between-black-mamba-and-leymannx).